# Hilbert transform: change the order of convolution and limit.

Tags: limits, convolution

The Hilbert transform of $f$ is 
$$Hf(t)=\lim_{y\to 0^+}[Q_y(t)*f(t)]$$
where $Q_y(t)=\frac{t}{\pi(t^2+y^2)}$ is the conjugate Poisson kernel.
Since 
$$\lim_{y\to 0^+}Q_y(t)=P.V\frac{1}{\pi t}$$
So the Hilbert transform of $f$ is given by 
$$Hf(t)=P.V\frac{1}{\pi t}*f(t)$$

---

Im a little confused by the statement. It seems that the order of limit and convolution are changed? Is it correct to change the order? Or I misunderstood ?

Comment: You need to assume some facts about $f$ to make $Hf$ well-defined, for example if $f$ is Schwartz then everything works well. Then you can extend  the operator $f \mapsto Hf$ to some larger space ($L^2$). As $\text{pv}.(\frac{1}t) = \frac{d}{dt} \log |t|$, if it converges then $Hf (t)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log |\tau| f'(t-\tau)d\tau$

Comment: I know that $f$ should be Schwartz. And I just can't understand why the limit and convolution can be interchanged. Is this because $f$ is Schwartz?

Comment: Yes. Let $g_y(t) = \int_{1}^t \frac{\tau}{\tau^2+y^2}d\tau$ and show that $\lim_{y \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_y(\tau) f'(t-\tau)d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log |\tau| f'(t-\tau)d\tau$